# Converting the 0-10V output of a PMT to a +- 10V dynamic range

Tags: amplifier, adc, light-sensor

I am trying to convert the output of a photomultiplier tube module (Hamamatsu HC120) which ranges from 0 to 10V to  +-10V in order to fit the full dynamic range of a ADC (MCC USB-205). To do so, I've implemented the circuit below using a TI TL074CN op-amp in order to substrat 5V with a gain of 2. The following values are used:

V1: signal 0-10V

V2: 5V

R1: 1.5 kOhm

R2: 0.75 kOhm

R3: 1.5 kOhm

R4: 3 kOhm

U1 : 12V

U2 : -12V

[image]

Initially, the signal voltage was set from 0 to 10V using an ajustable DC power supply, the output gave the correct +-10V range. However, when connecting the PMT module, the output of the circuit will only range from -10V to 5.5V.

At this point I've kind of run out of ideas to what could cause this. Some hypothesis I have included grounding problem or some current limitation from the sensor that saturates the output. I however lack the theoretical electrical engineering background to properly assess the problem.

How can this problem be solved?

Edit:

Here are the full connections schematics. As shown, I've grounded everything together. Could this be a source of the problem?

[image]

Datasheets:

USB-205 ADC https://www.microdaq.com/downloads/dl/file/id/79/product/900/measurement_computing_usb_200_series_data_sheet.pdf

Hamamatsu HC120
https://mi-lasers.com/wp-content/uploads/HAMAMATSU-HC120_series.pdf

TL074CN
http://www.ti.com/general/docs/suppproductinfo.tsp?distId=26&gotoUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ti.com%2Flit%2Fgpn%2Ftl074

Comment: A good starting point would be providing a link to the datasheet and describing in detail the connections. Your problem might be the output resistance of the sensor you're trying to use, in this case an INA amplifier would be better than an opamp

Comment: BEFORE you send signal into op amp, you should buffer sensor line to make sure there is (almost) no current draw from the sensor line. You may very well be pulling current from sensor, dropping its output voltage

Comment: just glanced at the datasheet: your amp is also NOT rail-to-rail, it doesn't go all the way to positive supply rail (12-13.5V with V+ = 15V). You're losing a little to that too. Find a rail-to-rail op amp as well!

Comment: I will give more detailled information on the connection, I'm working on the schematic. @Ilya, when you talk about buffering the sensor line. Does this simply mean adding a unity gain amplifier before my level shift amplification?

Comment: @Marc-Antoine exactly that

Comment: The saturation current on your PMT is microamps, and the gain is probably 100,000 or greater.  I think there is a good chance your dynamic range is limited by the saturation of the PMT and not the A/D, especially if you are oversampling. Have you calculated how many photon per sample you're getting at 10V output on the PMT?

Comment: I would increase all resistor values by 10 and use a much more quiet TL054 op-amp.

Comment: @Sparky256, what is the effect of increasing the absolute resistor values by 10kohm or 10 factor? My understanding was that the primary consideration is the ratio between R1 and R3 that sets the gain.

Comment: @valerio_new I've updated the original post with full connections and datasheets.

Comment: @user1850479 The PMT output is pre-amplified hence the output is a voltage between 0 and 10V. I am trying to shift this range between -10V and 10V to match the input range of the USB-205 ADC

Comment: @Marc-Antoine Yes I know that. Have you calculated how many photons per sample you are actually detecting for a 10v output?  Could you list the gain you are running the PMT at?

Comment: @Marc-Antoine If ALL R values increase by 10 then gain is the same, but the load seen by the source is now 15 K, not 1.5 K.